# Lumen : Send email doesn't work (Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded)

Tags: php, laravel, email, lumen

I'm trying to send emails on Laravel Lumen. My controller is :

```
$data = array('name'=>"test");
        Mail::send('emails.confirmation', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to('xxx.xxx@xx.fr', 'xxx')->subject
            ('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');
            $message->from('xx@xxx.fr','Virat Gandhi');
        });
return "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

I've a simple view with 2 lines of HTML.

But when I go on the page (in order to send mails) i don't have error in my code but this :
**Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

This error come from the Mail method, but I really don't understand why, with this simple code .. It should works fine...

Please help me, I'm on it from hours ... :(

Answer (score 1):

At first. In your case, it's better to use queues. Basic queue example in Laravel Documentation describing how to send confirmation emails.
At second. Are you sure that you correctly configured the mail driver? Could you provide your env file and log file here? (**of course without any private data (passwords, secrets, loging**))

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you**, I'm going to check for queues. For my current issue, here is my **.env** file (I use custom smtp server) :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=mail.xx.fr
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=hello@xx.fr
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hllo@xx.fr
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xx
```

I set `MAIL_DRIVER` to **"log"** in order to test without sending real emails.

What I've do to set my Mail driver is :

(Install illuminate/mail)

1. Add this line `$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);` to **app.php**
2. Add the lines bellow to **app.php** :

   $app->configure('mail');
   $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
   $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
   $app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
3. Create a new **mail.php** file into **/config/mail.php** like this file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php
4. Set the **.env** variables.

Here is my log file :

```
[2020-11-12 17:18:23] local.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at D:\\Dev\\GiftListAPI\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php:162)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve my issue : the problem was with my credentials. I put localhost on host and disable tls (my webmail server was on the same server than my website).
I really don't understand why I didn't have explicit errors btw.